# Java Interface\abstract class constriction

Tags: java, android, interface, abstract-class

Today, our team has the problem.

There is a class **AClass** that **implements** the interface **AInterface**. To date, we need to introduce a new entity(`BClass`) that would use only part of the interface A.

[image]

The first thing about which we think - split interface AInterface into 2 components (composition)

[image]
**The problem is that the logic `AClass->AInterface` - is a model prom pattern MVC. And we extremely do not want to cut it into several interfaces.**

We know that Java provides a mechanism for inheritance to extend a class or interface.

But is there any way to constrict the implementation? Or maybe exist another way?

*Note : we doesn't want use UnsupportedMethodException. Our goal - clean API.*

#### Update :

Next solution - not for us.

[image]

### GOAL :

[image]

Comment: Short answer: No (to constricting an interface), short of splitting it.

Comment: @user3580294 Your answer looks too unconvincingly.

Comment: What do you mean by unconvincingly? And yeah, it's short. That's why it's a comment and not a full answer.

Comment: @user3580294 not convincing.

Comment: Too convincing? I would say my answer isn't convincing enough, given the lack of info to back it up

Comment: @deathember I'm looking at your goal.  Say `BClass` implements `AInterface`, but doesn't provide `move` or `invalidate` methods.  Now, somewhere else, you have some other method `method(AInterface x)`, and that method wants to call `x.move()`, because if it's an `AInterface` it's supposed to have a `move()` method.  What behavior would you expect if `x` is actually an object of type `BClass`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your restricted subset into one interface, and have the larger interface extend it. Then have A implement the child (larger) interface, and B implement the parent (smaller) one.  Then both A and B implement the smaller interface, while only A implements the larger. Use the smaller interface for coding to whenever you can.

```
public interface AInterface {
    void add();
    void remove();
}

public interface ASubInterface extends AInterface {
    void invalidate();
    void move();
}

public class AClass implements ASubInterface { /* 4 methods */ }
public class BClass implements AInterface { /* 2 methods */ }
```

Comment: Your answer is a second picture in my question. I need a more painless way.

Comment: @deathember Not really. Notice how one interface extends the other.

Comment: @user3580294 actually this doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: @deathember Your second picture doesn't reflect what you described and what Ernest has provided. Also, your desire to want to keep the interface in one file may not match what it is you will need to do in order to solve your problem. You might need to consider relaxing this constraint or look for another approach if this won't work for you. It's pretty standard to see things like this.

Comment: @deathember What do you mean by "painless" way? This sounds pretty darn painless to me.

Comment: @user3580294 i want do not a make holywar with you. Understand me - MVC in commercial project is not a flexible thing.

Comment: So i just want an another solution. If that - is single solution we will use it. But now i do research about our problem.

Comment: @deathember I'm not trying to fight with you either. Could you give a more specific reason why this wouldn't work? You can still use `AInterface` exactly the way you had it if you implement this solution correctly.

Comment: @user3580294 i show you our goal. Give me a 2 minutes.

Comment: @deathember Can you give a specific reason why this answer wouldn't work? It provides exactly the behavior you outline in your GOAL diagram. You have `ASuperInterface` with `add()` and `remove()`. `BClass` implements `ASuperInterface`. Then you have `AInterface extends ASuperInterface`, adding `invalidate()` and `remove()`. Then you have `AClass implements AInterface`, which would require `AClass` to implement all 4 methods. Just like you wanted. And `AInterface` would behave exactly as it did before.

Answer (score 2):

The very fact that you have a usecase which only requires half of the methods exposed in the original interface tells you that you can further break that interface down. If you think about the design - how do your objects behave in your usecase scenarios, will tell you how it should be designed.

Just by looking at the names of the methods you have given, I'd expect them to be 2 different interfaces where AClass implements both the interfaces while BClass only implements the second interface.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "disable" polymorphism in certain cases, it's a major feature of the Java language.

If BClass shouldn't have those methods, then it shouldn't implent the interface.

AClass does more than BClass, so it should be another type. Why would you want them to be interchangeable?

On another note, many libraries use UnsupportedMethodException (like even the Java SDK with List collections). It just needs to be documented properly. So if you need ro use that to achieve your goal, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your needs seem a little strict but perhaps a abstract class could help.

```
public interface AInterface {

    public void add();

    public void remove();

    public void invalidate();

    public void move();
}


public abstract class BBase implements AInterface {
    @Override
    public abstract void add();

    @Override
    public abstract void remove();

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {};

    @Override
    public void move() {};

}

public class BClass extends BBase {

    @Override
    public void add() {
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
    }

}
```

Here I create a BBase which stubs out the two methods you want removed but leaves the other two abstract. BClass demonstrates how it would be used.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this if you compile AClass and BClass separately. I.e. compile AClass with the full version of the interface, then modify the interface (remove the methods) and compile BClass with this modified version of the interface.
P.S. By no means this is a painless approach.

Comment: This looks very dangerous, and I doubt that it will work.  For one thing, if you modify the interface, the compiler may think `AClass` needs to be recompiled too, since you've modified the interface.  If you do manage to fool the compiler into building everything like this, heaven only knows if it will work right.